# Why ♯$(o/I)^×＝NI-1$ holds?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be a imaginary quadratic field and $K$ has class number one.
Let $o$ be ring of integers of $K$. Let $I$ be prime ideal of $o$.

My pdf reads ♯$(o/I)^×＝NI-1$・・・①
(My pdf is Rubin's 'Tate Shafarevich groups of elliptic curves with complex multiplication').

My question :
What is $N$ ? There is no explanation about this in my pdf, and why does such a equation ① holds ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: In this context, $N(I)$ denotes the norm of the ideal $I$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_norm
. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015110/
.

Answer (score 0):

Since $o$ is an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, it follows that $I\cap\mathbb{Z}$ is a nonzero prime ideal $(p)$ of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Then $o/I$ is a finite integral extension of $F_p$, so $o/I$ is a finite field.

By definition, $N(I)=\text{#}(o/I)$, hence, since $(o/I)^{\times}=(o/I){\setminus}\{0\}$, we get $\text{#}(o/I)^{\times}=N(I)-1$.